# XML::Smart Parser in Perl

Tags: perl, xml-parsing

I'm continuing to work out of an outdated [bioinformatics book](http://books.google.com/books?id=bvY21DGa1OwC&pg=PA549&lpg=PA549&dq="bioinformatics+programming+using+perl+and+perl+modules"&source=bl&ots=gJZIZVNkpy&sig=AUj2GHbAUDbVlwI4haDYv_rUuv8&hl=en&ei=xb6XS-OOJpK-lAfP6e2UDQ&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=1&ved=0CAgQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22bioinformatics%20programming%20using%20perl%20and%20perl%20modules%22&f=false) and I'm attempting to use the XML::Smart Module.

I suspect the module's methods have changed over the course of 6 years and I'm inexperienced with perl to troubleshoot from [cpan source](http://search.cpan.org/~gmpassos/XML-Smart-1.6.9/lib/XML/Smart.pm#new_(FILE|DATA|URL_,_PARSER_,_OPTIONS)). The commented out code proves the ncbi.gov query functions, I'm having trouble with the 'new' method - it's not parsing the XML. What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

**Update** Specifically I'm running into trouble with parsing and displaying the Id array: `my @Id = $results->{eSearchResult}{IdList}{Id}{'@'};` I'm running this on OSX terminal and I don't see any Ids when I run this script. I am seeing the proper Count. Thanks!

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl
# use lib "/Users/fogonthedowns/myperllib";
# use LWP::Simple;
use XML::Smart;
use strict;

#Set base URL for all eutils
my $utils = "http://eutils.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/entrez/eutils";
my $db = "Pubmed";
my $query ="Cancer+Prostate";
my $retmax = 10;
my $esearch = "$utils/esearch.fcgi?" . 
              "db=$db&retmax=$retmax&term=";

# my $esearch_result = get($esearch.$query);
# print "ESEARCH RESULT: $esearch_result\n";
# print "Using Query: \n$esearch$query\n";
# print "hello world\n";

my $results = XML::Smart->new($esearch.$query,"XML::Parser");
my $count = $results->{eSearchResult}{Count};
my @Id = $results->{eSearchResult}{IdList}{Id}{'@'};
my $all_Id = join("\n", @Id);

print "Count = $count\n";
print "$all_Id\n";
```

Comment: Why are you using an outdated book?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing you have done wrong is to comment out `use strict`, the second is to use `-w` instead of `use warnings`.

With strict turned on, perl will report:

> Bareword "XML::Parser" not allowed while "strict subs" in use at tmp:test.pl line 19.

This lets us trace where the problem is occurring.

The [examples in the documentation say](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?XML::Smart) that the second argument (the parser to use) should be quoted, and you haven't quoted it.

So we change to:

```
my $results = XML::Smart->new($esearch.$query,"XML::Parser");
```

… and it runs.

(Incidentally, the language is called ["Perl", not "perl" or "PERL"](http://faq.perl.org/perlfaq1.html#What_s_the_differenc))

Comment: I'm running this from OSX terminal. I don't see an array (or anything for that matter from the print "$all_Id\n"; command. Shouldn't this return 10 Ids?

Follow the link: http://eutils.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/entrez/eutils/esearch.fcgi?db=Pubmed&retmax=10&term=Cancer+Prostate

Answer (score -1):

change:

`my @Id = $results->{eSearchResult}{IdList}{Id}{'@'};`

to:

`my @Id = $results->{eSearchResult}{IdList}{Id}('@');`

Comment: This should be edited into the question, not added as an answer.

Comment: you perl people are up tight. This was an obvious mistake I made, and it is the solution that solved the problem. Thus an answer. I'm going back to my ruby book now.